# Can't getImageData() in javascript with gif file; can with FillRect. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixel, getimagedata

Looks like getImageData works when I use FillRect to create a rect on the canvas, but it doesn't work when I draw a gif on the canvas despite it drawing correctly and everything. Have no idea why that is - is it a security risk? Help?

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="230" height="60" src="http://www.thekitmaker.com/image/3.gif" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="230" height="60" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
function getPixel(imgData, index) {
  var i = index*4, d = imgData.data;
  return [d[i],d[i+1],d[i+2],d[i+3]] // [R,G,B,A]
}

// AND/OR

function getPixelXY(imgData, x, y) {
  return getPixel(imgData, y*imgData.width+x);
}


window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    //draw on canvas
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10,50,50);//,0,0);// c.width,c.height);
    //ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    //ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

    //get image data
    alert("h");
     var imgData = ctx.getImageData(10, 10, 50, 50);
    alert("h2");
    // The magic®
    //getPixel(idt, 852);  // returns array [red, green, blue, alpha]
    alert("p:"+getPixelXY(idt,1,1)[0]); // same pixel using x,y
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that image of yours is being served without the required cross origin authorizations so `getImageData` is being disallowed due to a tainted canvas. BTW, add `crossorigin='anonymous'` to your img element so it requests the cross origin authorizations when it loads: `<img crossOrigin='anonymous' id="scream" width="230" height="60" src="http://www.thekitmaker.com/image/3.gif" alt="The Scream">`

Comment: Turns out that you're right. If I load the file off the hard drive, it works correctly. So this means the solution is to store the image on the same server as the page, which actually shouldn't be that hard since they offer 'image hosting' of sorts. Now I just have to figure out how/where to store the image...

Comment: Wait, would it raise a red flag if the image was on http://i.ebayimg.com/ and the page was on www.ebay.com?

Comment: Probably yes. Although they can pull the images from i.ebaying.com and route them through the ebay.com servers.

Comment: Man, chrome and firefox allows 'anonymous' but internet explorer doesn't. Why is it always IE that has to ruin my day? lol (Just checked, apparently I need the crossorigin anonymous checkmark to allow the image from ebay's image server to getImgData(). But doesn't work in IE.)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is because of security reasons. If you draw an image from a different origin onto a canvas, the canvas will be marked as "tainted" and you can no longer get image data from it, among other things.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#security-with-canvas-elements